# How to reference UILabel strong reference programmatically using Swift?

Tags: swift, ios8, uilabel, strong-references

Using Swift, I have a UILabel that was created programmatically in the viewDidLoad override function:

```
var middleDate = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: (screenWidth / 2) - 45, y: 0, width: 90, height: 20))
    middleDate.text = "3:13:46 PM"
    middleDate.font = UIFont(name: "ArialMT", size: 13)
    middleDate.textAlignment = .Center
```

Which works great.

Then I am trying to change the text in the override function `viewDidAppear`.
I get Build Failed with the message `Use of unresolved identifier 'middleDate'`

If I use interface builder and drag and drop a UILabel on the view, then give it a strong reference it works great. Is there a way to reference a programmatically created object with a strong reference?

Or am I going about this incorrect?

---

This is what I have on my ViewController.swift:

I have a feeling that there is a much better and cleaner way to do this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    var middleDate = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: (screenWidth / 2) - 45, y: 0, width: 90, height: 20))
    middleDate.text = "3:13:46 PM"
    middleDate.font = UIFont(name: "ArialMT", size: 13)
    middleDate.textAlignment = .Center

    self.myTopView.addSubview(middleDate)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0,
        target: self,
        selector: Selector("getLocalTime:"),
        userInfo: nil,
        repeats: true)

    let mainLoop = NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop()
    mainLoop.addTimer(timer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

    func getLocalTime(timer: NSTimer) { 

        var todaysDate:NSDate = NSDate()
        var dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        var centerDateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm:ss"            

        var DateInFormat:String = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(todaysDate)            

        middleDate.text = "hello"


    }
}
```

Comment: Have a class memner: "var middleDate: UILabel?". Use same in viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear.

Comment: I am adding 'var middleDate: UILabel?' to the viewDidLoad and the viewDidAppear and I am getting errors. errors: UILabel does not have a member named 'text'. And where is created the UILabel and added to the sub view I am also getting errors

Comment: The code you provided does not display a UILabel on the view. It makes a local variable containing a UILabel which is reinitialized as soon as viewDidLoad exits. If you are adding the label to your view at some later point, how are you getting a reference to the label in your viewWillAppear? You don't show that code. In short, we need to see more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var middleDate = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: (360 / 2) - 45, y: 200, width: 90, height: 20))

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        middleDate.text = "3:13:46 PM"
        middleDate.font = UIFont(name: "ArialMT", size: 13)
        middleDate.textAlignment = .Center

        self.view.addSubview(middleDate)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) { super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        middleDate.text = "hello"
    }
}
```

Your issue was middleDate was declared with local scope within the viewDidLoad function.  In order for it to be a class variable you need to  declare it at the class level.  I simplified the class a little just to make it work quickly for me.

Comment: for a few unique Labels that's the way to go, but if i was creating an array of UILabels to be iterated over as part of an update, then that's beyond my knowledge